# return row number where cell is similar to string

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How could I get the row number of my if statement?

```
  private void load_session_value()
    {
        string trans_id = Session["transaction_id_report"].ToString();
        string trans_number = Session["transaction_no_report"].ToString();

        //string grid_value_id = GridView1
        //string grid_value_num
        if (trans_id != null && trans_number != null)
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                if (row.Cells[1].Text.ToString() == trans_id && row.Cells[2].Text.ToString() == trans_number)
                {

                    row.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#A1DCF2");
                    //GridView1.SelectedIndex = rowIndex;
                    GridView1.SelectedIndex = ???

                    GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(new object(), new EventArgs());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I need the row number for my `GridView1.SelectedIndex` currently the `row.color` is getting on the right row. But if possible could I get the `rownumber` that has the `row.color`?

Comment: int currentRow = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;

Comment: will return the row number of my inner most if statement?

Comment: It returns the current cell which is the selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just switch your `foreach` statement with a `for` statement..

```
for (int i = 0; i <  GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    ...
    GridView1.SelectedIndex = i;
}
```